# Incident does not contain a definition for the new field when creating a new attribute in CRM 4.0 SDK

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a c# integration on an old install of CRM 4.0.  Everything has been working (mostly) until I created a new attribute in the incident that I want to populate.

When I try to map to it, intellisense gives me an error that Incident does not contain a definition for the new field (`hm_operator`).

I have verified the field name as well as the fact that I published the change.  I've also restarted IIS and closed out of Visual Studio and gotten back in.

```
Guid ContactIDGuid = new Guid(contactid);
CrmSdk.CrmService myCrm = new CrmSdk.CrmService();
myCrm.Url = GetCrmServiceForOrganization(organizationName);
CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken myToken = new CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken();
myToken.AuthenticationType = 0;
myToken.OrganizationName = organizationName;
myCrm.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = myToken;
myCrm.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

CrmSdk.incident newIncident = new CrmSdk.incident();
newIncident.customerid = new Customer();
newIncident.customerid.type = "contact";
newIncident.customerid.Value = ContactIDGuid;

newIncident.hm_initialcontact = new CrmSdk.CrmDateTime();                
newIncident.hm_initialcontact = Utility.ConvertToCRMDateTime(DateTime.Today);

newIncident.hm_caseowner = new Picklist();
newIncident.hm_caseowner.Value = Convert.ToInt32(1);

newIncident.hm_operator = operatorinfo; // error occurs here

Guid newIncidentId = myCrm.Create(newIncident);
return newIncidentId.ToString();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Naturally, as soon as I posted the question, I found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From within Visual Studio you have to update the web references in your project for it to see any new attributes.